# Zendesk app integration

Tags: zendesk

I created a web application by using HTML, JS, JQuery, and some Jquery plugins. Now I want to integrate it into Zendesk. Can I use it like just copy all my files and paste it into zendesk zip file ? Or Do I have to re-code entire thing to make it work for ZenDesk ?

I checked the examples in online, they didn't mentioned anywhere about reusing the apps that already developed in Zendesk.

Comment: What do you want to do with zendesk?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently doing some fairly extensive Zendesk integration. If you are referring to customisation on the Agent Portal side then it will have to be a Zendesk App under strict Zendesk adopted frameworks jquery is included (http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/). If in the customer facing Help Center you can simply go into there on screen editor and paste your html, js, etc into the relevant sections see (https://support.zendesk.com/entries/22618341)

Good luck,
Tris

Comment: @spenf10 I'm doing zendesk integration with database, the requirement is to how the DHL tracking details of the customer orders in a side bar of the agent home portal. SO is there anyway we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate your app to Zendesk as an Agent App, you might consider the chance of using within an [iframe](https://www.zendesk.com/apps/iframe/).

Note that the url to which the iframe is pointing to must be served as HTTPS. Otherwise, it won't work.

EDIT:

As of version 2.0 of ZAF (Zendesk Application Framework), it's easy to integrate any webpage. In v2.0, you aren't restricted to any technology or environment.